# How can I find the list of arguments for any syscall?

Tags: macos, system-calls

I've found a list of syscalls in Mac OS X in /usr/include/sys/syscall.h.  However, I can't find any description of what arguments are expected by what functions.  Could somebody please point me towards the correct resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reference for OSX system calls with parameters is here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1504.3.12/bsd/kern/syscalls.master

Comment: It would be better to summarize the answer here in case that link breaks.